# camel spring xml jpa transaction route not starting in standalone mode

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jpa

I tried to apply jpa transaction manager with spring transaction policy to one route. As a result, it is starting and thrown below issue. could you please let me know the cause of the issue and solution.Could you please share any quick-starts of camel jpa transaction for standalone mode. I can find quick-starts for fuse and server mode.

```html
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 240 type converters
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry INFO  Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] JpaComponent                   INFO  Using EntityManagerFactory configured: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean@147d849
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] JpaComponent                   INFO  Using TransactionManager configured on this component: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@a9b98d
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.spring.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:458)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.<init>(Lorg/apache/camel/CamelContext;Lorg/apache/camel/Processor;Lorg/apache/camel/util/CamelLogger;Lorg/apache/camel/Processor;Lorg/apache/camel/processor/RedeliveryPolicy;Lorg/apache/camel/Processor;Ljava/lang/String;ZZLorg/apache/camel/Predicate;Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;Lorg/apache/camel/Processor;)V
 at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.<init>(TransactionErrorHandler.java:70)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder.createErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder.java:110)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy.createTransactionErrorHandler(SpringTransactionPolicy.java:124)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy.wrap(SpringTransactionPolicy.java:108)
 at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.createProcessor(TransactedDefinition.java:162)
 at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
 at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
 at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3301)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3024)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
 at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
 at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:205)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:154)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
 at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:390)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:87)
 ... 6 more
[ERROR] *************************************
[WARNING] thread Thread[Timer-0,5,org.apache.camel.spring.Main] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[Timer-0,5,org.apache.camel.spring.Main] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[derby.rawStoreDaemon,5,derby.daemons] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 2 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=org.apache.camel.spring.Main,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:778)
 at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:491)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please add more details about your problem. Without the route that throws that error or even configuration code (since the problem arise through adding a transaction manager), there is little chance to help. Try to reduce your code to the minimal base to show the problem and post that code in your question. Sometimes the reduction already helps to identify the problem and question becomes obsolete :-)

Comment: the problem while applying transaction to route. without transacted, the route is working fine.

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` could have its roots in a classpath problem. Have you got mixed Camel versions in your classpath? All Camel dependencies must be from the same version. Same applies for Spring dependencies